# Show specific line in html textbox/ textarea

Tags: html

So I have an HTML textbox/ textarea and inside that, we display some text. Now the textbox is about 4 lines tall but the text can be several more lines tall so for that we have enabled scrolling.

however, what I would like is that a certain line number or if a possible line starting from the input text automatically scrolls to become the first row in the html txtbox/ textarea.

how is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this with an html `textarea` or `text box`, I've tried extensively to style `textarea` content separately from the box, but research suggests it's not possible. However, you can 'imitate' a textbox with a `div`, to choose where the content visibility starts and have full CSS styling. The text inside this `div` scrolls automatically to the second paragraph. You can still scroll up and read the previous text.

```js
window.onload = function() {
var begintext = document.getElementById('begin');
var topstart = begintext.offsetTop;
document.getElementById('textarea').scrollTop = topstart;
};
```

```css
/* optional font family import */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v13/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0IT4ttDfA.woff2) format('woff2');
}

#textarea {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;  
    overflow: auto; 
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.79rem;
    line-height: 0.95rem;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 0 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div id = "textarea">
<p>Delicacy is prized in pinot noir and riesling. In California, the main stylistic difference in Cabernet Sauvignon is between hillside / mountain vineyards and those on flatter terrain like valley floors.
A wine has legs if it sticks to the inside of the glass when swirled. A lingering finish indicates a luscious vintage!</p>
<span id = "begin"><p>Burgundy is the definition of a strong red. Fruity flavors, with aromas of rose petals, peaches, and allspice. Grapes crushed and ready for fermentation are called must. All grape juice is white, only the skins of purple grapes contain the dark pigment. A "butt" is a medieval measurement for the liquid volume of wine. Acid, tannin, fruitiness, oakiness, are all components of balance.</p></span>
<p>Trichloroanisole in the cork can impart musty, mouldy overtones. Such a wine is called "corked." Egg whites are sometimes used in the clarification process. The best wines impart a lingering, complex and rich finish. Text from www.wineipsum.com</p>
</div>
```